# Validate Due Date less than 12 months

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column-formula

I have a field named "Due Date" and I am trying to add validation so users cannot enter a date more than 12 months from today (current date). This is SP2010.

I've tried this formula in the List / Validation Settings.

```
=[Due Date] < DATE(YEAR(Today()),MONTH(Today())+12,DAY(Today()))
```

I can't get it to work. I enter a due date which is greater than 12 months from now and it doesn't show me the user message. It allows me to enter the date.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
=[Due Date] < DATE(YEAR(Today())+1,MONTH(Today()),DAY(Today()))
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**: Add this formula inside **Column Validation** under **Column Settings**.

Comment: Thanks your method works as we as my previous formula. I ended up finding that since I was using the formulas in the List Settings / Validation Settings it would not work. When I moved the formula from there to the Column Validation settings they worked.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Comment: And Yes, I tried your formula and it was working for me as well.