# Validation setting for Date Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, validation, column-validation

I want to apply validation setting so that my "ActionDate" should be always greater than 2 year and 6 month. I can able to set greater then today but how to set it should greater then 2 year and 6 months?

```
=OR([ActionDate]>TODAY(),ISBLANK([ActionDate]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=OR([ActionDate] > DATE(YEAR(Today())+2,MONTH(Today())+6,DAY(Today())),ISBLANK([ActionDate]))
```

[Validate Due Date less than 12 months](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281758/validate-due-date-less-than-12-months/281760#281760)

Comment: Try using this in column-validation, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks it works i changed according my requirement