# Date Column Validation - Check if Date is less than 10 days from Today

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, modern-experience, sharepoint-list, column-validation

I have created a column named **Departure Schedule** and its type is `Date and Time.

However, I need to check that the **Departure Schedule** should not be less than 10 days from `Today()`.

Is it possible to code under SharePoint's Column Validation to check if the **Departure Schedule** entry is not less than 10 days from `Today()`, and if it is, a message will be shown "Departure Schedule should be more than 10 days from the date of request"?

I have tried entering this code ([from this topic](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281758/validate-due-date-less-than-12-months)) under Column Validation

```
=[Departure Schedule] < DATE(YEAR(Today()),MONTH(Today()),DAY(Today())+10)
```

There were no Syntax error, but also there were no messages shown even if I entered a date that is less than 10 days from `Today()`.

[image]

Example:

[image]

Date today is 9/25/2020 - No validation messages shown after entry

I'm new to SharePoint's Column Validation - any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below formulas and check which one works best for your requirements:

```
=IF([Departure Schedule] < DATE(YEAR(Today()),MONTH(Today()),DAY(Today())+10), FALSE, TRUE)
```

OR

```
=IF([Departure Schedule] < (Today()+10), FALSE, TRUE)
```

OR

```
=[Departure Schedule] >= (Today()+10)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you are not considering things like working days and weekends, the simplest formula `=([Departure Schdule]>=(TODAY()+10))` shall be enough for your list.